# What on earth is causing this script to fail? No console errors, works fine in CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Banging my head against the wall on this one..

Here's an example of how this is supposed to work: https://codepen.io/connorv/pen/ExNZKKp

Simply it just waits 4 seconds and then adds the class 'blue' to an element with class 'animated'. Here is the jQuery itself:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    animated.addClass('blue');
}, 4000);
```

But on this live page the script never seems to run. http://apkeaton.wpengine.com/work/ (Search 'blue' in inspector to quickly bring up the inline script here)

I'm misunderstanding something huge here.. Both the site and CodePen use jQuery 3.5.1 and there doesn't seem to be any syntax issues, what is causing this script to not run on the live site but work fine in a CodePen? I've tried using .ready() and even onLoad but no matter when I load this it never seems to run.

Comment: No `.animated` element exists on pageload `view-source:http://apkeaton.wpengine.com/work/` Figure out what's adding that class, then change your code to run *after* whatever it is

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for your help - this gives me a lot to go on & is definitely the problem I'm having. Sorry for this awful low quality question..